# react native post form data with object and file in it using axios

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, fetch, multipartform-data

[image]

so i want to upload 
object as data 
and file as Note 
to api using axios

```js
uploadToServer= () => {
    const file =this.state.photo

  let data2 ={sale_id:1,
            note_type_id:4,
            description:"test",
            note_content_item:" hi from broker hub"
            
            }



let data = new FormData()
data.append('data[sale_id]', '1')
data.append('data[note_type_id]', '4')

data.append('data[description]', "test")

data.append('data[note_content_item]', "test")







console.log(data)


axios({
  url: api',
  method: 'POST',
  data: data,
  headers: {
   
            'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data',
          'Authorization':'Basic YnJva2VyOmJyb2tlcl8xMjM='

  }
})
        .then(resp => console.log(resp.data.response))
        .catch(error => console.error(error)); 

}
```

first i am trying with data without Note i can do it in postman

[image]

but with my code i got error

message: "Can not save file"
response_code: 10

i got this error only if i change the key from data to something else
[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are not building `FormData` correctly, Try this:

```
let data = {sale_id:1,
                note_type_id:4,
                description:"test",
                note_content_item:" hi from broker hub"            
                }
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(data));
formData.append('Note', {
                     uri: "file://" //Your Image File Path
                    type: 'image/jpeg', 
                    name: "imagename.jpg",
                  });
axios({
       url    : api,
       method : 'POST',
       data   : formData,
       headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    'Authorization':'Basic YnJva2VyOmJyb2tlcl8xMjM='
                }
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                    console.log("response :", response);
           })
           .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log("error from image :");
           })
```

Comment: Even I am following the same approach, but it's not working for me.

Comment: @bubble-cord  what error/issue you getting, share your code so can understand your problem.

Comment: I used same code but not working getting error from image : [Error: Network Error] , Kindly help, i already waste too much time, thank you in advance

Comment: Please add a note that `FormData` is from `form-data` package i.e. from 

```import FormData from 'form-data'```

I was struggling to find what's the right one as the default FormData was pointing to VS Code app's internal one which is incorrect.

Comment: `let updateModal = {
      Id: 1,
      CompanyName: this.state.companyName,
    };

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(updateModal));
    formData.append(
      'CompanyLogo',
      // null,
      this.state.companyLOGO.uri
        this.state.companyLOGO.uri
    );
 axios({
      url: apiUrl,
      method: 'PUT',
      data: formData,
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    }) 
  };`
getting server error 500

Answer (score 30):

when you are using react-native you don't need "form-data" package. Because react native polyfills standard [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) api and exports it as global.

second problem is axios converts form data automatically to string, so you need to use transformRequest config on request to override it.

```js
import { AxiosRequestConfig } from "axios";
const FormData = global.FormData;

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'example.com', // use with scheme
    timeout: 30000,
    headers: {
        "X-Platform": 'iOS',
        "X-App-Build-Number": '1.0.0',
    },
});

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("userId", "123456");
formData.append("file", {
    uri: "/dev/sda/abc.png",
    type: "image/png",
    name: "abc.png",
});

const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    method: "post",
    url: "/process/start",
    responseType: "json",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        // if backend supports u can use gzip request encoding
        // "Content-Encoding": "gzip",
    },
    transformRequest: (data, headers) => {
        // !!! override data to return formData
        // since axios converts that to string
        return formData;
    },
    onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
        // use upload data, since it's an upload progress
        // iOS: {"isTrusted": false, "lengthComputable": true, "loaded": 123, "total": 98902}
    },
    data: formData,
};

// send post request and get response
const response = await axiosInstance.request(config);
```

Comment: `transformRequest` was the key for me. It can even be `transformRequest: (data) => { return data}` and it works

Comment: Thanks a lot. transformRequest was what was needed. I've been stuck with this for a while. Thanks again

Comment: Thank you so much, `transformRequest` fixed it! Interestingly, for me the requests broke after upgrading axios from `0.24.0` to `0.26.0`. Before this, I was sending form data without `transformRequest` and it was working just fine ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It seems the following PR introduces the breaking change affecting react-native: https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3757#issuecomment-1081931773

Comment: Saved my day! The ``transformRequest`` option did the fix.

Comment: Super helpful! Thank you so much! Could you link some sources where we could find more info about how "react native polyfills standard FormData api and exports it as global"

Answer (score 0):

formData.append("file", {
uri: //file.uri,
**type:"multipart/form-data", // type must be multipart/form-data**
name: file.name,
});

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

**This might help you:**

```
import {Platform} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

    const upload = async readPath => {
    console.log('path', readPath);
    const URL = 'your-url';
    const headers = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${projectSecret}`,
      },
    };
    const formData = new FormData();
    const file = {
      uri:
        Platform.OS === 'android' ? `file:///${readPath}` : readPath,
      type: 'text/plain',
      name: name,
    };
    formData.append('file', file);

    await axios
      .post(URL, formData, headers, {
        timeout: 3000,
      })
      .then(async response => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('error : ', error);
      });
  };
```