# Passing formData to upload image with nodeJS (Multer) -> 'react-native-image-crop-picker'

Tags: react-native, multer, form-data

I have currently a problem when i want to uploads files from client mobiles devices to my backend (NodeJS) with MULTER.

I'm using 'react-native-image-crop-picker' to pick the images on the devices (from the library or the camera)

I have used formData to make the response as file to the backend but the req file is still undefined.

My front-end Code:

```
let response = await ImagePicker.openCamera({
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
    cropping: true,
  });<br>
  let media = {
    uri: response.path,
    type: response.mime,
    name: response.filename,
  };<br>
  let form = new FormData();
  form.append('uploads', media);<br>
  if (form !== null) {<br>
    await Axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: url,
      data: form,<br>
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    })
```

My backend :

```
   router.post('/article', upload.single('uploads'), async (req, 
   res) => 
   {<br>
      try {
       console.log(req.file);
 } <br>catch (err) {
   console.log(err.message);<br>
  res.status(500).send('SERVOR ERROR');
 }
  });
```

[front-end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWtsu.png)

[back-end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L81j.png)

console.log(req.file) = "UNDEFINED"

Comment: `media` is not a `File`(or a `Blob`) it is just a plain object.

Comment: So how send the file ?

Comment: RESPONSE from 'react-native-image-crop-picker'  => {"cropRect": {"height": 1944, "width": 1944, "x": 0, "y": 324}, "height": 400, "mime": "image/jpeg", "modificationDate": "1607988557000", "path": "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.client/files/Pictures/109ddea7-1e04-436d-a7b7-63ba0daafdd1.jpg", "size": 95232, "width": 400}

Comment: I guess you'll have to read the file from `response.path` into a Blob and pass that to the FormData object.

Comment: See my response, the problem is the same ...

Comment: Try using a read stream `form.append('uploads', Fs.createReadStream(response.path));`

Comment: It s the same. Req.file = UNDEFINED Req.body = { uploads: { _parts: [ [Array] ] } }

Comment: let form = await new FormData();
        form.append('uploads', RNFetchBlob.fs.readStream(response.path));
        let d = {};
        d.uploads = form;                                                                                                          
        Req.body => { uploads: { _parts: [ [Array] ] } }
       Req.file => undefined

Comment: You might have to check the docs on your FormData implementation to see what you need to get a file uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I have used to try with fs.readFile :

```
  let d = {};
  let e = await Fs.readFile(response.path, 'base64');
  let form = new FormData();
  form.append('uploads', e);
  d.uploads = form;
  let config = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'};
  Axios.post(url, d, config)
    .then((res) => console.log(res))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}
```

The req.file is still undefined but the req.body shows this :

```
req.file => undefined
req.body => { uploads: { _parts: [ [Array] ] } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to read the file or turn it into a blob, as [this tips page](https://github.com/g6ling/React-Native-Tips/tree/master/How_to_upload_photo%2Cfile_in%20react-native) shows and [this post debugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56235286/react-native-post-form-data-with-object-and-file-in-it-using-axios), it is likely easier to use react-native's built-in mechanism to turn images into form-data.

In your case, your problem was likely to do with the data that you are passing like filename or path, log them to make sure they are valid, for example filepath for react-native-image-crop-picker [only works on iOS](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/blob/9cfde20678d4fc9c094c9be5e53d2bb376579040/index.d.ts#L400) and it may require some manipulations like `.replace('file://', '')` as [experienced by others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71336078/axios-post-request-sending-nothing-with-multipart-form-data-react-native-ex?rq=1)