# React Native + Expo + Axios file upload not working because axios is not sending the form data to the server

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-native, axios, native

I am trying to upload an image with react native front end and axios to my back end.

#### This is how pic the image

```
const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: false,
      aspect: [9, 16],
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(result.uri);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      console.log(result);
      setPhoto(result);
    }
  };
```

now you can see clearly that I am setting up the photo state with the ImagePicker library.

#### Then I create a form data instance:

```
     let img_to_upload = {  
        type: 'image/jpeg',    
        name: 'random-file-name',  
        uri: Platform.OS === 'android' ? photo.uri : photo.uri.replace('file://', ''),
    };  

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("title", 'this is tandom text');
    formData.append("file", img_to_upload);
```

here you can see clearly I have initiated a formdata object and then adding two fields to the form.

1. title
2. file

#### And last but not least, I send this to the server:

```
axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: U_R_L,  
      data: formData,
      transformRequest: (d) => d, 
      headers: { 
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=------random-boundary",
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
       console.log("response : ");  
       console.log(response.data);    
    }, (error) => {
        console.log("error : "); 
        console.log(error); 
    })
    .then(() => {
      setProgress(false);
    });
```

But it never sends any file to the server.

Here is the error:

[image]

But when I test the same endpoint with my REST client, it works.

Comment: You're passing local file URI  in FormData payload which is not relevent. You have either fetch imsge as base64 or blob data

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do this? I mean convert the local image to blob

Comment: `const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
      resolve(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
      reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
    };
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.open("GET", "LOCAL_FILE_PATH_HERE", true);
    xhr.send(null);
  });`

Comment: follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489502/how-to-upload-file-to-server-using-react-native/72998342#72998342

Answer (score 8):

Axios' FormData is broken since v0.25 for react-native.
They tried to optimize the FormData detection util for no real reason. Unfortunately, the proper detection fails for non browser environments.

You can find a workaround here for now:
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4406#issuecomment-1048693170

TL;DR

```
const formData = new FormData();
...
const response = await axios.post('/URL', formData, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
  transformRequest: (data, headers) => {
    return formData; // this is doing the trick
  },
});
```

Just pass a transformRequest and return your formData and everything will "work" magically again. This is a workaround though (I've spent 5 hours on this issue) and should hopefully be fixed in an upcoming version.

Comment: Here is another one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56235286/react-native-post-form-data-with-object-and-file-in-it-using-axios/71116822#71116822

Regarding the comment, it is even enough to just return "data" (which indeed did work for me as well)

Answer (score 1):

there is no no need to set the `content-type` header in your request. It automatically identify your request contains the `buffer data`. so you just pass the request without setting `multipart content-type` header.

I'm also confused with this same issue. my MacBook is sending the request without any issue by using postman, and my android device is having issues sending the `multipart` request.

**Solution**

Poor network connection is the major issue in this part. So just change your mobile network to any other network, which has the better internet connectivity. and check again. surely it solved your issue

Native javascript query for sending the multipart data - axios is also using this same native library

```
 var data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", {
                          name: 'image.png',
                          type: 'image/png,
                          uri: 'file:///file-cache-url'
                        }, "image.png");
     
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    
    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
      if(this.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
      }
    });

xhr.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:3000/data/upload");

xhr.send(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch image as BLOB

```js
 const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
      resolve(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
      reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
    };
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.open("GET", "FILE_URI_HERE", true);
    xhr.send(null);
  });
```

Comment: and is this the blob variable  which I need to add in the formData later?

Comment: Yeah. your backend should receive BLOB data parse them then save to image format like JPEG - I authored blog for image upload with firebase you can use it as reference  https://expofire.hashnode.dev/upload-image-with-expo-and-firebase-cloud-storage

Comment: This might be one way to do it but I think changing the upload server just for once instance is not a good solution. I am looking for a solution which would allow me to upload the image via formData.

Comment: Can you save the image as Base64? I guess it's just string and easier to handle with FormData

Comment: But what's wrong with sending the image as the local location? It was working before, and I recently updated the axios version on my expo app and this stopped working.

Comment: I have no insight what reason but that's what recommended by Expo team

Comment: I posted an answer with a workaround which does not rely on BLOB

Answer (score 0):

The transformRequest method [used here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71345289/16135310) of solving this issue is not working on me so I did a workaround of using JSON.stringify.

```
const formData = new FormData()
...

MyApiInstance.post('endpoint', JSON.stringify(formData)).then(() ...
```

hope this help someone.