# Cant upload image to node.js server using react native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, file-upload, axios

i think i'm about to shoot myself in the foot.... I'VE BEEN TRYING TO UPLOAD SINCE WEEKS an image to a node.js server but nothing seems to work..... please for god sake help me out !

I have a form where the user enters the product data + its image. everything works fine except for the image. the user chooses an image from a library, but when i send this image to upload it on server side nothing works. Here's my code

```
const handleSubmit = async (listing) => {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("description", listing.description);
    data.append("category", listing.category.label);
    listing.images.forEach((image, index) => {
      data.append("images", {
        name: "image" + index,
        type: "image/jpeg",
        uri: image,
      });
    });

    await axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/products/addProduct", data)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
};
```

When i console.log the image uri

```
file:///Users/zakisb/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/83E12EA5-E8FA-4850-82C1-84021B25450D/data/Containers/Data/Application/AF39E1CC-D48A-4D8E-A28B-D82718E12096/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FLokazz-app-5f4724db-b9d7-45aa-a8ca-ac5acf2f4780/ImagePicker/5579DD93-038A-4EB3-8C37-8105DC7990E2.jpg
```

my backend ( using multer )

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./images");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
  },
});

router.post(
  "/products/addProduct",
  upload.single("images"),
  async (req, res) => {
   
    try {
      res.send("ok");
    } catch (err) {
      res.send("Error " + err);
    }
  }
);
```

note that i tried this way of making the api call

```
await axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/products/addProduct", data, {
        headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=123456`,
       }
      }))
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

same problem... THE IMAGE DOESNT GET UPLOADED !

Please note that the backend is working fine. i tried uploading and image using insomnia/postman and the image gets uploaded successfully. i need to fix the api call. WHAT AM I DOING WRONG? PLEASE HELP !

Comment: if it's multiple files, then it's `.array('images')`. maybe try with fetch instead of axios

Comment: check which formdata you're using: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56235286/react-native-post-form-data-with-object-and-file-in-it-using-axios

Comment: @traynor not multiple, only one file

Comment: try it https://codesandbox.io/s/axios-post-form-m55p99?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @DmitriyMozgovoy didnt work... i'm using react native by the way

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the storage object that you are creating from multer like this?

```
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'uploads') // *change this to whatever location you want*
      },
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname)
      }
    })
    
    **var upload = multer({ storage: storage })**

// upload single file

app.post('/uploadfile', upload.single('myFile'), (req, res, next) => {
  const file = req.file
  if (!file) {
    const error = new Error('Please upload a file')
    error.httpStatusCode = 400
    return next(error)

  }

 
    res.send(file)
 
})
//Uploading multiple files
app.post('/uploadmultiple', upload.array('myFiles', 12), (req, res, next) => {
  const files = req.files
  if (!files) {
    const error = new Error('Please choose files')
    error.httpStatusCode = 400
    return next(error)
  }

    res.send(files)
 
})
```