# axios network error when uploading file from react native using laravel api

Tags: laravel, react-native, axios

It only gets network error when i try to add image to the formdata.
Other api calls like my login and fetching of items are working fine but when i try to add image it throws this error.

```
const newItem = async () => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  const headers = new Headers();

  headers.append('Content-Type','multipart/form-data');

  const imageData = {
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    uri: image.assets[0].uri,
    name: 'upload.jpg'
  }

  formData.append('image', imageData);
  formData.append('user_id', userInfo.data.id);
  formData.append('title', title);
  formData.append('description', desc);
  formData.append('price', price);
  formData.append('bid_start', bidStart);
  formData.append('bid_end', bidEnd);
  formData.append('winning_bid', price);

  // console.log(imageData)

  try {
    const res = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/items`,formData);
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data)
  }
  
  catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

};
```

here is the error response from the debugger, please do bear with me on this.

```
{
    "message": "Network Error",
    "name": "AxiosError",
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "env": {
            "FormData": null
        },
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        "method": "post",
        "url": "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/items",
        "data": {
            "_parts": [
                [
                    "image",
                    {
                        "type": "image/jpeg",
                        "uri": "file:///data/user/0/com.waste_mobile/cache/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_acebc359-4515-4d0e-aa20-aa3fefdaa63f.jpg",
                        "name": "upload.jpg"
                    }
                ],
                [
                    "user_id",
                    3
                ],
                [
                    "title",
                    "asdasd"
                ],
                [
                    "description",
                    "asdaasd"
                ],
                [
                    "price",
                    "50"
                ],
                [
                    "bid_start",
                    "2022-10-17T16:20:24.412Z"
                ],
                [
                    "bid_end",
                    "2022-10-17T16:20:24.412Z"
                ],
                [
                    "winning_bid",
                    "50"
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    "code": "ERR_NETWORK",
    "status": null
}
```

i also added my item controller on the api route of my laravel backend

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'user_id'=>'required',
            'image'=>'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048',
            'title'=>'required',
            'description'=>'required',
            'price'=>'required',
            'bid_start'=>'required',
            'bid_end'=>'required|after:bid_start'
        ]);

        $response = array('message'=>'','data'=>'','success'=>false);
        if($validator->fails()) {
            $response['message'] = $validator->errors();
            return Response::json($response);
        }
       
        $request['winning_bid'] = $request['price'];
        $image = "";

        if($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $extention = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = time().'.'.$extention;
            $file->move('uploads/items/', $filename);
            $image = $filename;
        }

        //manual add image name
        //do not alter code below
        $item = Item::create(array_merge($request->all(),['image'=>$image]));
        
        $response['message'] = "Item successfully added.";
        $response['data'] = $item;
        $response['success'] = true;
        return Response::json($response);
    }
```

Comment: ERR_NETWORK may suggest the server isn't running or related to a CORS issue. What is the details from `error.response`? Also sharing your route and the file it belongs to (web.php or api.php) would be helpful too!
Pasting the output of the error.response would be useful as an image doesn't help other users if it one day gets deleted and can not be used for indexing for searches.

Comment: server is already running, only on this part when i add image. the routes are correct too. @haakym post is updated with the error response

Comment: Is this the correct URL `http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/items` - it's not supposed to be `https`? Where is the route defined, in `api.php` - just wondering if it's CORS related or something to do with XSRF middleware.

Comment: yes that is the correct route as it throws validation errors from the laravel api when i ommit "image" on `Route::apiResource('items',ItemController::class);`

Comment: Sorry I'm a little stumped on the issue, consider looking at similar questions like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56235286/react-native-post-form-data-with-object-and-file-in-it-using-axios
Also, it may be worth checking the error log in laravel when you hit the backend to see if that reveals anything

Comment: im gonna try this link, anyhow laravel side works as expected. no erros what so ever except for request validation errors which is expected.